# How to do a forEach loop in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How would I make a forEach loop in a discord.js embed? I am trying to send out a list of all warns in 1 embed. This is due to me not knowing how many warns a user has (hardcoded amount). This is due to it being able to be changed.

I have tried to look this up to find a way to do this but can't because of how specific this is and it can't just be googled easily. I am unable to find a way to do this other than sending the messages alone and not all together.

Comment: In the end, you're going to send a string through the embed. Iterate through the warns and concat to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let modifiedArr = fetched.map(function(element){
    return element.content + " ";
});
```